# Is it safe to install the nvidia-current driver and then have this HDD in another pc that has nvidia graphics

Tags: compatibility, nvidia

My PC has nvidia chipset + nvidia graphic card. Both built in and removable. The second PC , in which this HDD will be installed has just a nvidia chipset with integrated graphics. I'm not sure if my PC specs are the same as the other one. So, if i install it here will it still work there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second computer doesn't have an Nvidia card, I think you should remove the driver. Otherwise, it will auto-load, and prevent the integrated GPU from working properly.

If both computers have Nvidia cards, then it should work. I've done it before with two notebooks. The original had Geforce 7400go, and the other one Geforce 9300m. Both cards worked well with the nvidia-current driver - 270.41 at the time.

Comment: it has an integrated nvidia video card. Will it be ok? @mikewhatever

Comment: It should, provided the two require the same Nvidia driver. I'll update the answer with relevant info in a sec.